# SQL - Remove All The Users and Create A New User With Admin Role Via PhpMyAdmin

Tags: login, sql

It is very easy to remove all the users and add a new user with administrative role via wp admin panel. But the requirement is to achieve this through SQL.

I can trunc `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` table to remove all the users. But when I add an entry in `wp_users` with dummy data and then login through wp admin then it says incorrect login. Why?

I shall be very thankful to you if you can tell me the proper way of removing all the users and adding a user with admin role.

Comment: What reason is there for doing this via SQL and not via an mu-plugin that uses the APIs? I'd also say that the use of PHPMyAdmin is irrelevant to your question as it's merely an SQL client

Comment: If you're not adding meta like `wp_capabilities` when you insert a user via SQL, no wonder you get incorrect login. Are you also hashing the password field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit and run the below SQL query in your database.

Make sure there are no users with the existing ID you specify. If there are change all instances in all 3 tables, currently set to **4** to another number that does not yet exist.

```
INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES ('4', 'demo', MD5('demo'), 'Matt Royal', 'youremail@yourdomain.com', 'http://mattroyal.co.za/', '2014-06-09 00:00:00', '', '0', 'Matt Royal');


INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');


INSERT INTO `databasename`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'wp_user_level', '10');
```